# Update variable for new file path

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I've written a filename to variable

```
output = '/tmp/file'
output = os.path.abspath(output)
```

Then I moved the file

```
shutil.move(output, '/tmp/modified/')
```

How should I properly update the variable output modified by `shutil.move`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shutil.move` returns the destination:

```
output = shutil.move(output, '/tmp/modified/')
```

Edit on python2 `shutil.move` doesn't return. so if you have the destination you can just set output equal to it:

```
shutil.move(output, destination)
output = destination
```

If you need the absolute path you can use `os.path.abspath(destination)`

Comment: >>> output = os.path.abspath('/tmp/test2')

>>> output = shutil.move(output, '/tmp/modified/') 

>>> print output
None

File in fact moves, but variable becomes  None

Comment: in python3 shutil moves. I guess in python 2 this isn't the case. See edit